# Sending an object when instantiating a new class in PHP

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, phalcon

Good day.

I have a PDO (PostgreSQL) object to perform actions in the database in my Phalcon framework, the problem is that I'm implementing some Oauth server classes I found, and need to pass this object to the classes of the Oauth server so it can be able to perform actions to the database...

This is how the classes are created:

The database object:

```
$di['db']
```

And how I'm sending it to the classes:

```
// Initiate the auth server with the models
$server = new League\OAuth2\Server\Resource(
    new League\OAuth2\Server\Storage\PDO\Session($di['db'])
);
```

The Session.php file:

```
<?php

namespace League\OAuth2\Server\Storage\PDO;

use League\OAuth2\Server\Storage\SessionInterface;

class Session implements SessionInterface
{

public functions that will need to use the database object...
```

But the object is not available in the Session.php file, so how can I have access to it from the new classes?

Thanks.

Comment: `function __construct(Database_Name $db) { $this->db = $db; }`? with a  `private $db;` ? Allowing access as `$this->db->do_function()` ? the **`Database_Name`** in the construct would be your database classes name of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a private variable and Add a constructor to the class in Session.php

```
private $database;

public function __construct($database) {
    $this->database = $database;    
}
```

Once you have your Session object instantiated, you will be able to access the database object in your Session object's methods by doing

```
$this->database->do_something();
```

I would suggest adding type hinting to the constructor but since I don't know what object type the $database is supposed to be I am leaving it off. You can read more about type hinting here:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php

Comment: Good answer, thanks for expanding on my comment & good description.